# Setting Security cookie using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, cookies, resttemplate

I am trying to call a  Restful JSON service using RestTemplate and Jackson json convertor. Now in order to call the service I need to pass in a Security cookie. I can achieve this by using URLConnection (See the code below)

```
URL url= new URL("https://XXXXXXXX");

URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
yc.setRequestProperty("SecurityCookie", ssocookie.getValue());
```

Whats the parallel for this in RestTemplate? Here is a code snippet which I have been using to call a Restful Service using RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();  
InputBean input = new InputBean();  
input.setResource("SampleResource");  
HttpEntity<InputBean> entity = new HttpEntity<InputBean>(input);  
ResponseEntity<OutputBean> response1 = rest.postForEntity(
    "https://XXXXXXXXX", 
    entity, OutputBean.class);
```

I can not figure out how to pass the security cookie while using RestTemplate to call the service. Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the underlying `HttpURLConnection` used by `RestTemplate` by wiring your `RestTemplate` up with a custom [`ClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html), which lets you access the underlying connection to set headers, properties, etc. The `ClientHttpRequestFactory` is used by `RestTemplate` when creating new connections.

In particular, you can extend the [`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html) implementation and override the `prepareConnection()` method:

```
public class YourClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {
  @Override
   protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) {
     connection.setRequestProperty("SecurityCookie", ssocookie.getValue());
   }
}
```

Comment: I also have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698072/simpleclienthttprequestfactory-vs-httpcomponentsclienthttprequestfactory-for-htt) on `RestTemplate` in which I am having doubts on `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementations. See if you can help me out if possible. I am stuck on this for a while. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This answer is outdated - the other answer is better.

Answer (score 38):

I wrote a blog post that explains how to do this using request headers:

http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/08/sending-cookies-with-resttemplate/

Here's the code:

```
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getValue());
HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);
ResponseEntity rssResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
    "https://jira.example.com/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/18107/SearchRequest-18107.xml?tempMax=1000",
    HttpMethod.GET,
    requestEntity,
    Rss.class);
Rss rss = rssResponse.getBody();
```

Comment: Seems `HttpEntity` [is abstract](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) since apache http 4.0. Is there a way to keep using this?

Comment: To clarify, this is Spring's HttpEntity class rather than Apache's.

Comment: Oops! Could you provide the required libraries and imports for your example? I'm becoming crazy with an Android + spring project. Same class names everywhere!

Comment: They are in the spring-web library, org.springframework.http package.

Comment: This only works with exchange. If you want to use methods like getForObject it doesn't

Comment: That's right. The getForObject() and related methods are really just convenience methods for the more general-purpose exchange() methods.

Comment: The link is dead for me now, but available on the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150320081025/http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/08/sending-cookies-with-resttemplate/

Comment: While this will work, you still have to add the header to each `HttpEntity` individually. I'd prefer a more general approach, e.g. configuring the `RestTemplate` bean appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it has worked for us

```
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getValue());
```